# Horizontal scroll only if child element's width property exceeds parent element's max-width property

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm wondering how this can be achieved...

I have code similar to the code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/usLgo4go/).

I have an unordered list with a set `max-width` (inherited from parent) that contains many list items that should have automatic widths. The issue I am having is that when `width:auto` is set, the element conforms to its parent's `max-width` property and when `width:*length*` is set to a specific length that is larger than the parent's `max-width` property (i.e. `400px` in the attached fiddle), the element's output is similar to what is desired, but not exactly what is desired.

The desired result is for the list items to have *automatic* widths, but not conforming to the parent's `max-width` property. The list items should:

1. Have a **width equal to** the total width of the **content it provides** (which is undetermined for each element)
2. **Not** be **multiline** (each element should be 1 line max)
3. **Not overlap** the parent element (i.e. using `position:absolute;`)
4. **Only** be **scrollable if its width exceeds the parent's width**

I would prefer a purely HTML/CSS solution, however I will use a JS/jQuery solution if need be

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="scroll1">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>I have some text here that is longer than 300px width, but its width is undefined (width can be between 0 and whatever)</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>I have text here less than 300px wide</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="scroll2">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>I have some text here that is longer than 300px width, but its width is undefined (width can be between 0 and whatever)</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>I have text here less than 300px wide</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#scroll1, #scroll2 {
    max-width:300px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul {
    max-width:inherit;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
}
li {
    max-width:inherit;
    overflow:auto;
}
li:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color:#ddd;
}
#scroll1 li div {
    width:auto;
}
#scroll1 li div {
    width:400px;
}
```

---

Thank you for your help!

P.S. I am sorry if this question has already been asked, I was not able to find a duplicate of it. If there is an existing answer out there, I am more than willing to accept it as an answer or remove this question if a result that is given fully answers this question.

Comment: add overflow-x:scroll to the divs inside the list items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will get you part way there. White-space:nowrap will keep everything on the same line

```
#scroll1 li>div {
width:400px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow:scroll
```

}

Comment: `white-space:nowrap` is exactly what I was looking for, thank you